# Difference between these two HMAC excamples?

Tags: java, cryptography, hmac

I have to calc HMAC signature to compare to the one from a message.
I come to two different results and do not understand the difference nor which one is correct.

I have even tested different online HMAC validators and get both version from different web sites.

the message: `7914073381342284::TestMerchant:TestPayment-1407325143704:1130:EUR:AUTHORISATION:true`

the key: `44782def547aaa06c910c43932b1eb0c71fc68d9d0c057550c48ec2acf6ba056`

result 1: `/b1O7eDkBtlZ3I1xH+qMl/I1aRBDel8Y4sbLZXnDKEI=`

result 2: `coqCmt/IZ4E3CzPvMY8zTjQVL5hYJUiBRg8UU+iCWo0=`

I guess that result 2 is the correct one.

Java code calculating the first result:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class HMAC {
    static public byte[] calcHmacSha256(byte[] secretKey, byte[] message) {
        byte[] hmacSha256 = null;
        try {
          Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
          SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "HmacSHA256");
          mac.init(secretKeySpec);
          hmacSha256 = mac.doFinal(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Failed to calculate hmac-sha256", e);
        }
        return hmacSha256;
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String message = "7914073381342284::TestMerchant:TestPayment-1407325143704:1130:EUR:AUTHORISATION:true";
          String key = "44782def547aaa06c910c43932b1eb0c71fc68d9d0c057550c48ec2acf6ba056";
          
            try {
              byte[] hmacSha256 = HMAC.calcHmacSha256(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
              
              //Output of HEX
              System.out.println(String.format("Hex: %064x", new BigInteger(1, hmacSha256)));
              System.out.println("Base64: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSha256)); 
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
}
```

Java code comming to the second result

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SignatureException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class HMACValidator {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, SignatureException {
        

          String message = "7914073381342284::TestMerchant:TestPayment-1407325143704:1130:EUR:AUTHORISATION:true";
          String key = "44782def547aaa06c910c43932b1eb0c71fc68d9d0c057550c48ec2acf6ba056";
        
        HMACValidator demo = new HMACValidator();
        String result = demo.calculateHMAC(message, key);
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    public static final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

    // To calculate the HMAC SHA-256
    public String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, SignatureException {
        try {
            if (data == null || key == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            byte[] rawKey = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
            // Create an hmac_sha256 key from the raw key bytes
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
            
            
            // Get an hmac_sha256 Mac instance and initialize with the signing ey
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);

            mac.init(signingKey);

            // Compute the hmac on input data bytes
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
            
            // Base64-encode the hmac
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawHmac));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing data or key.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Websites
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online is doing it "wrong"
https://cryptii.com/ is doing it "correct"

[image: correct]

[image: wrong]

Comment: You get the result `coqCm...` if the key is hex decoded and the result `/b1O7...` if the key is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: see here: [hex decoded](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'44782def547aaa06c910c43932b1eb0c71fc68d9d0c057550c48ec2acf6ba056'%7D,'SHA256')From_Hex('Auto')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=NzkxNDA3MzM4MTM0MjI4NDo6VGVzdE1lcmNoYW50OlRlc3RQYXltZW50LTE0MDczMjUxNDM3MDQ6MTEzMDpFVVI6QVVUSE9SSVNBVElPTjp0cnVl)

Comment: and: [UTF-8 encoded](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'44782def547aaa06c910c43932b1eb0c71fc68d9d0c057550c48ec2acf6ba056'%7D,'SHA256')From_Hex('Auto')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=NzkxNDA3MzM4MTM0MjI4NDo6VGVzdE1lcmNoYW50OlRlc3RQYXltZW50LTE0MDczMjUxNDM3MDQ6MTEzMDpFVVI6QVVUSE9SSVNBVElPTjp0cnVl)